# MongoDB on kubernetes Community Operator. Statefulset pods on unique nodes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm deploying a mongodb cluster with the [MongoDB Community Operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator). ReplicaSet configuration.

I followed [this example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/config/samples/arbitrary_statefulset_configuration/mongodb.com_v1_hostpath.yaml) for my configuration. The difference is that I want a pod on each node with his pv on the node. At every deploy the same node location pod/pv.

I have deployed a mongodb statefulset with two replicas. I want that pods of the statefulset `pod-0`, `pod-1` lays on specific nodes: `node-0`, `node-1`.

For the two pods I deployed two persistent volumes of type `hostpath`. One for each node: `pv-0` and `pv-1`.

All seems fine but there is **The problem**:
Sometimes the PVC of `pod-0`(forced on node-0) is bounded to pv-1 (foce on node-1) or vice-versa. So the pod can't start because there is a node conflict

Is there a way to force `pod-0` on the same node of `pv-0`?

Maybe with the `MongoDBCommunity.spec.statefulSet.VolumeClameTemplates`, but I can't figure out how.

I read [HERE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/), but I can't figure out how to apply to statefulset.

Follows my yamls. Satefulset:

```yaml
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: my-mongo
  labels:
    app: my-mongo
  namespace: mongo-system
spec:
  members: 2
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
      volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: data-volume
        spec:
          storageClassName: hostpath
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 11Gi
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              type: data
```

PV

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data-volume-db-0
  labels:
    type: data
spec:
  storageClassName: hostpath
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  capacity:
    storage: 11Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/volumes/db-data
    type: ""
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      # This is just an example for matchexpression
      # This field is required depends on the specific
      # of the environment the resource is deployed in
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node-0

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data-volume-db-1
  labels:
    type: data
spec:
  storageClassName: hostpath
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  capacity:
    storage: 11Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/volumes/db-data
    type: ""
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      # This is just an example for matchexpression
      # This field is required depends on the specific
      # of the environment the resource is deployed in
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node-1
```

Comment: Can you try by deploying a pod on a specific node by following this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodename) ?

Comment: Nope, I can't because the pod is managed by the statefulset. I solved with a simply `claiimRef` on the PV definition. Later I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved using the `claimRef` on the PV yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data-volume-db-1
  labels:
    type: data
spec:
  storageClassName: hostpath
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  capacity:
    storage: 11Gi
  claimRef:
    namespace: system-mongo
    name: data-volume-db-0
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/volumes/db-data
    type: ""
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      # This is just an example for matchexpression
      # This field is required depends on the specific
      # of the environment the resource is deployed in
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node-1
```